# Local area network connection is not visible

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, lan

I have a Lenovo t42 with with Windows XP SP3.

The "Local area network connection" is not visible in Network Connections. The Ethernet controller and adapter driver is properly install (no yellow signs). All Network services are also running properly.

The network is working fine, and getting an IP address from DHCP but has to restart the DHCP service once after booting.

Comment: To clarify: you mean that in the Network Connections window, there is no icon representing your Ethernet card?

Comment: @goblinbox : Yes Sir. Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Even though the ethernet controller is properly installed you should download the latest drivers from Lenovo and re-install it. Lenovo tends to have a few bugs in there drivers these days and the stock standards ones might not be compatible with XP SP3.